# How to connect VirtualBox guest to the host using a VIRTUAL cross-over cable?

Tags: virtualbox, ubuntu-14.04, wired-networking, crossover-cable

Is it possible to configure an Oracle VitualBox guest settings such that is connected to host by a virtual cross-over cable?

Answer (score 1):

Generally: Aside from being [entirely](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_crossover_cable#Automatic_crossover) [obsolete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medium_Dependent_Interface#Auto_MDI-X), a "cross-over cable" is also specific to copper Ethernet wiring and makes absolutely no sense in virtualized networks. You just use a *regular* cable (or "cable").

In VirtualBox: You get a direct host↔guest connection by selecting "Attached to: Host-only adapter". (If there aren't any available host-only adapters, create one in *Preferences → Network*.)

[image: (screenshot)]

---

(…Okay, that's not 100% the same. The "host-only adapter" is a virtual switch, and by default VirtualBox runs its own DHCP server on it as well. But if you turn off DHCP in Preferences, then it is completely indistinguishable from a direct cable connection.)

Comment: Did you mean that if turn off DHCP in Preferences, then it is completely indistinguishable from a patch cable connection (not a cross-over cable connection)?

Comment: @PHPLearner: Again, cross-over is just a hack to deal with copper Ethernet wiring. On a _virtual_ network, you have no wires to cross over, so there's no "patch" vs "crossover" cable either; you just _connect things_. (Besides, even on real hardware, Auto-MDIX has been a thing for _decades_. Though, sure, I don't run a datacenter, just a tiny university network, so maybe I just never had a reason to care.)